# Ethereum node url and port on local

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, mix

I've geth node running on my local and I need to find out http url and ethereum url to deploy dapp on Mix IDE. Can any one please help and tell where to find these two parameters ?

Comment: HTTP-RPC (JSON) should be at http://127.0.0.1:8545 not sure what an Ethereum URL is supposed to be.

Comment: On hitting localhost:8545 from browser I get response as "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}". Not clear about how to run it properly.